# what's the logic behind 'default credentials' to authenticate bigQuery client

Tags: java, authentication, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I saw two ways to authenticate bigQuery java client

```
/**
 * Creates an authorized Bigquery client service using Application Default Credentials.
 *
 * @return an authorized Bigquery client
 * @throws IOException if there's an error getting the default credentials.
 */
public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {
    // Create the credential
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);

    // Depending on the environment that provides the default credentials (e.g. Compute Engine, App
    // Engine), the credentials may require us to specify the scopes we need explicitly.
    // Check for this case, and inject the Bigquery scope if required.
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
        credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
    }

    return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Bigquery Samples")
            .build();
}
```

and this

```
public class QuickstartSample {

    public static void Main() {

       // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
       string projectId = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID";

       // Instantiates a client
       BigqueryClient client = BigqueryClient.Create(projectId);

       // The id for the new dataset
       string datasetId = "my_new_dataset";

       // Creates the dataset
       BigqueryDataset dataset = client.CreateDataset(datasetId);

       Console.WriteLine($"Dataset {dataset.FullyQualifiedId} created.");
    }
}
```

what does this mean?

`default credentials (e.g. Compute Engine, App Engine)`

It won't be able to access my specific GCP project, right?

so what is the point of these `default credentials` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "application default credentials", the application uses its own service account as opposed to the end-user's service account. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication#app-default-cred for more details.